# How do I access my webcam in Python?

Tags: python, webcam

I would like to access my webcam from Python.

I tried using the [VideoCapture](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/) extension ([tutorial](http://technobabbler.com/?p=22)), but that didn't work very well for me, I had to work around some problems such as it's a bit slow with resolutions >320x230, and sometimes it returns `None` for no apparent reason.

Is there a better way to access my webcam from Python?

Comment: Please clarify which operating systems you need to support.

Comment: See also: [Python library for taking camera images](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/18134/1834)

Comment: And: [Why are webcam images taken with Python so dark?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28566972/562769)

Comment: John Montgomery's, answer is great, but at least on Windows, it is missing the line vc.release()
before cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
Without it, the camera resource is locked, and can not be captured again before the python console is killed.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

OpenCV has support for getting data from a webcam, and it comes with Python wrappers by default, you also need to install `numpy` for the OpenCV Python extension (called `cv2`) to work.
As of 2019, you can install both of these libraries with pip:
`pip install numpy`
`pip install opencv-python`

[More information on using OpenCV with Python](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html).

An example copied from [Displaying webcam feed using opencv and python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11449901/660921):

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
    cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break

vc.release()
cv2.destroyWindow("preview")
```

Comment: There is Python 3 support if you install from wheel. I used this tutorial successfully: https://www.solarianprogrammer.com/2016/09/17/install-opencv-3-with-python-3-on-windows/

Comment: You have also to release the camera otherwise will be open even if the window is closed: vc.release()

Answer (score 4):

gstreamer can handle webcam input. If I remeber well, there are python bindings for it!

Comment: `padsp streamer -q -c /dev/video0 -f rgb24 -F stereo -r 24 -s 1280x720 -t 00:10 -o test.avi` will record 10 seconds of an HD webcam with 24 fps and save it as *test.avi*. (Notice that padsp is just used to ensure that audio is captured under the newer Ubuntu versions.)