# Unhandled exception at Canny edge detector

Tags: c++, opencv, canny-operator

I want to try Canny edge detector, but when I try to start I receive an Unhandled exception:

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF97F6C8B9C in canny_project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000002485D89860

Below is the code that I implemented In VS2012.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    namedWindow("Edges", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);

    cv::Mat frame; cv::Mat out; cv::Mat out2;

    while (1) {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        GaussianBlur(frame, out, Size(5, 5), 0, 0);
        cvtColor(out, out2, CV_BGR2GRAY); // produces out2, a one-channel image (CV_8UC1)
        Canny(out2, out2, 100, 200, 3); // the result goes to out2 again,but since it is still one channel it is fine

        if (!frame.data) break;
        imshow("Edges", out2);

        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if (c == 'c') break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add a if(frame.empty()) after the capture to handle cases where capturing failed?

Comment: And test whether capture object was opened succesfully!

Comment: I have added if(frame.empty()) . It's not empty... Any ideas?

Comment: if the image isnt empty I dont see any problem (afaik device -1 should work too, but not sure about the C interface)... Please try  `cv::VideoCapture capture(-1); if(!capture.isOpened()) return 0; ` instead of `cvCaptureFromCAM` and  `if(!capture.retrieve(frame)) return 0;` instead of  `cvQueryFrame` lines...

Comment: do you known the format of your input images produced by the capture? maybe its BGRA instead of BGR? Can you try to remove the cvtColor and the canny operation and instead save the images to disk with `cv::imwrite` or just display the images without any previous operation?

Comment: Could the fucntion cvQueryFrame be the reason?
I have found this: The returned image should not be released or modified by the user.

Comment: please try to avoid the cvXXX functions because they use C interface. switch to `cv::` functions and objects! Could you remove the whole cvtColor and canny operations and just `cv::imshow` your image? if that works, the problem is definitely not the capturing. If that doesnt work, the capturing is your problem!

Comment: I find a dependence. If frame is a cv::Mat, I have a problem with capturing and showing (frame is really empty). So, how to  find out the type of capturing video and create a mat frame, which have the same format?

Comment: so you capture a frame but it is black? sounds like an Alpha channel... please print mat.channel() and mat.cols() and mat.rows()

Comment: It's zero. 
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
If frame is mat, everything is zero. If it's IplImage* it works correct and function cvShowImage shows video from camera.

But in this case cvcvtColot doesn't work.
I have found the simple problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430367/opencv-webcam-capture-problem

However, their solution do not help

Comment: Please try to use cv::Videocapture object!!

Comment: I use it. However, frame is still empty

Comment: I have tried about 6-8examples and in all cases I have a problem with cvcvtcolor.... I despair

Comment: if the frame is empty (cols == 0 or rows == 0) it's obvious that cvtColor crashes. if it is not empty, please tell me what mat.channels is equal to!!

Comment: mat.channels equals 1.
mat.rows=0 and mat.cols=0

Comment: so your capturing just doesnt work. no need at all to look at cvtColor or canny until you are able to capture the images! which device do you try to use for capturing?

Comment: I have 3 different web cams. The first camera is integrated into the laptop. Two other are Intro digital PC cam. As I said if I use IplImage as the format of images, it's work and I see the result. Is it possible that the case in getting new frame? Now I use this structure: cap >> frame;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this instead and tell me whether images are shown or not and try different device numbers too:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    cv::namedWindow("Capture");
    int deviceNum = 0; // please try different device numbers too like -1, 1, 2, ...
    cv:VideoCapture capture(deviceNum); 
    cv::Mat frame;

    if(!capture.isOpened())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open device " << deviceNum << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while (true) 
    {
        capture >> frame; // = cvQueryFrame(capture);

        //if (!frame.data) break;
        if(frame.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "could not capture a legal frame" << std::endl;
```

continue;
                //break;
            }
            cv::imshow("Capture", frame);

```
        char c = cv::waitKey(33);
        if (c == 'c') break;
    }
    std::cout << "press any key to exit" << std::endl;
    cv::waitKey(0); // wait until key pressed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2039: 'isOpen' : is not a member of 'cv::VideoCapture'

I have commented  if(!capture.isOpen()) condition. CApture window is grey. No errors or exceptins

Comment: typo, must be .isOpened ()

Comment: could not capture a legal frame

Comment: I have another laptop with Win 7 x64, same version of VS, opencv e.t.c. And everything works perfect.

Comment: I find a regularity. This program works correct only first time after restart PC. At second and further it write "could not capture a legal frame"
Could it be the problem with destructor?

Comment: can you please remove the break and add a continue there instead?

Comment: It works!! Magic... I see "could not capture a legal frame" in the console, but I see capture from camera. Thank you!! Could you explain this, please?

Comment: maybe your device does not provide legal frames in each iteration but once in a while... but I have no idea why this happens. I never had that problem myself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably you are using cvCaptureFromCAM wrong.

```
cvCaptureFromCAM(0) // not -1
```

Why do you use OpenCV with C-Code? Use VideoCapture instead CvCapture.

Comment: Same error... I have tried canny for usual images and it works properly. I suppose there are some problems with format or size of images...

Answer (score 0):

`cvCaptureFromCAM(-1)` has wrong argument, use 0, if you have just one camera connected. In addition, in C API, when you finished working with video, release `CvCapture` structure with `cvReleaseCapture()`, or use `Ptr<CvCapture>` that calls `cvReleaseCapture()` automatically in the destructor. Have a try, please, [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nikhil9/4080630/raw/OpencvCam.c) example, to see if you access your camera properly.

Comment: Same error... I have tried canny for usual images and it works properly. I suppose there are some problems with format or size of images...

Comment: At what function exactly do you face the exception? Do you access properly your camera at all?

Comment: I am quite sure that cvtColor(out, out2, CV_BGR2GRAY);
Cause  program stops at the next line. And no matter what is it.
I have tried another example of Canny edge and the same error after the same string.
I have a acceess to camery. I tried another examples with using camera and it's work properly

Comment: please print the number of channels and type, directly after capturing.

Comment: I suggest, also, using C headers, not C++: `#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
`

Comment: Please, suggest which fuctions will be better to use for capturing number of channels and type?
Now, I'm using CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0); for capture
Could I use cvGetCaptureProperty? If yes, I don't know which flag should I use?