# Capturing webcam stream in Python using OpenCV - Need help

Tags: python, linux, opencv, webcam

I'm running Python2.7 on Arch Linux. I installed OpenCV via Pacman.

The Python code I'm using is:

```
import cv

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
```

Very simple. All I'm trying to do, for now, is get Python access to my webcam. But that above code outputs:

```
[user@host python]$ python2.7 webcam.py 
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
```

My webcam works fine with Cheese (linux webcam program). So, presumable, there shouldn't be any driver/module issues...

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried with python 2.6? I heard rumours saying that there may be problems with 2.7... just rumours...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: [Displaying a webcam feed using OpenCV and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601194/displaying-webcam-feed-using-opencv-and-python)

It appears that you're not passing .CaptureFromCAM() the right argument. If there is only one camera, you can do something like this:

```
    capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
```

The -1 tells it to just grab whatever camera it can find (see [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#capturefromcam)).