# How can I access my webcam using python or c

Tags: python, c

I want to create a GUI application which will access the local webcam  and provide a feature of taking the snapshot from the stream . I want to develop this application using C/python .  can anyone tell  me how can I access my local webcam.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python API to access webcam stream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604749/python-api-to-access-webcam-stream)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OpenCV](http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-opencv/) which has Python bindings to capture webcam streams.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [VideoCapture](http://videocapture.sourceforge.net/), it is "A Win32 Python Extension for Accessing Video Devices".

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, you can use [v4l2](http://v4l2spec.bytesex.org/spec/) by which you can get the full control of your webcam.