# Interfacing of webcam with Arduino

Tags: image, arduino

I am doing a project of automation in which I want to check if an object is OK or NOT by using a USB webcam.

So I am using a proximity sensor to detect if object is in front of the webcam. If it is there, I want to send a signal to the webcam to capture an image via [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). How do I do that?

After capturing the image, data will be saved and processed in the Arduino. How do I do the webcam & Arduino interfacing?

Comment: not only is this question hideously off-topic ... it shows no effort in research at all.

Comment: This is best asked on the electrical engineering stack exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would use the proximity sensor to continuously read values and in case there is a change, the Arduino can send a signal over the serial port.

On the computer side, you can read from the serial port and trigger the webcam using a script.

In [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), it is possible using the [PySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) module and it is easy to link Python scripts to a webcam to take pictures. [Read an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604749/python-api-to-access-webcam-stream).

(You should do some more research on this. There are already a lot of solutions out there to trigger using sensors. See this one for high speed photography: http://www.glacialwanderer.com/hobbyrobotics/?p=11)

Comment: Thanx... Actually I am new to arduino.. And I dont know python or python script lang... So I was looking for some simple solution. But I think now I have to learn it.. Ill try for this solution...

Comment: There is no shortcut to learning. Try exploring the Arduino forums and go through the basic tutorials on http://arduino.cc. If this was helpful then do accept it as an answer so the question doesn't remain open.