# Can Python Be Uses to control hardware like web cams on a PC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, project, hardware

So i am working on a project alone, and i would like to know if python can be used to **control/manage hardware** connected to *PCs*. It would be very helpful. (also please mention if it can work on popular Operating Systems i.e -  Windows, Linux, macOS)

I haven't tried anything yet as i would like to gain some insight first

i don't have code, because this is a *query* and i want to know what to do.

the expected result is me being able to continue with my project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are receiving downvotes because it is not wise to write "I haven't tried anything yet" and "i don't have code" on a forum designed to help people with code they've written. That said, whether or not you can control attached hardware with Python depends on whether the manufacturer/unaffiliated developers created a Python API for it (it will be device specific). You will get more mileage out of this question if you can edit it to include the specific device you have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python runs on Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Yes, you can control your web cam and other hardware.

To control your webcam: [How do I access my webcam in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604749/how-do-i-access-my-webcam-in-python)

Mouse and keyboard: https://steemit.com/python/@howo/how-to-control-the-mouse-and-keyboard-with-python-for-automation

Python is a high level language so if you wanted to do stuff like writing drivers, microcontrollers (There is Micropython), etc, it would be better to choose a language like C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on the specific hardware you want to use.

Also, python runs on all major operating systems.