# integrating OpenGL with webcam in python language

Tags: opencv, opengl, pyopengl

how to integrate webcam texture with the OpenGL in python language . i didnt get any example on internet

plzz answer

Comment: This question is a valuable one, but it desperately needs edits.  The edit queue is full, so surely you could take a moment to accept some of them in order to make a more useful StackOverflow for everyone.  plzz edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always in Programming, I would start by splitting the problem into smaller Problems:

1. Getting the webcam feed (if you do not have it already)
   For getting webcam data I would start here: [How do I access my webcam in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604749/how-do-i-access-my-webcam-in-python) (Basically get the webcam feed using OpenCV or GStreamer)
2. Make sure the data is in an 1D array in RGB color format
3. Once you have video feed from the camera, it should be fairly straight forward to take the newest frame and upload it to a OpenGL texture using GL.glTexImage2D. ([example](https://gist.github.com/binarycrusader/5823716a1da5f0273504#file-textured_tri-py-L59))

   This is assuming you to be familiar with OpenGL already, if not, you can try to follow some OpenGL tutorials until you feel comfortable enough for step 3.

Comment: It's worth noting that #2 isn't strictly necessary, and in some applications, using something other than RGB may be useful.  Specifically, be aware that OpenCV typically works with BGR, and this is what's returned when getting data from the webcam using OpenCV.